# upper bound to show finiteness of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable such that $f'$ is continuous. What would be a 'nice' upper bound for $$I:=\int\sup_{z\in B(x-y,1)} |f'(z)| \;\; dy,$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, where $B(a,r)$ denotes the ball centered at $a$ of radius $r$, if I want to show that $I<+\infty$.

Thank you!

Comment: It isn't clear what $I$ is: the supremum is a function defined in terms of $x$ and $y$, so that after integration in $y$ you get $I$ as a function of $x$. You are asking for an upper bound for $I(x)$ that implies $I(x) < \infty$?

Comment: Yes. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: $f'$ should be bounded, otherwise $I$ can not be bounded.

Comment: If I am interpreting this correctly (as per Umberto's comment), then I believe it is false. For example, let $f(y) = e^y$. The supremum value is then $e^{x - y + 1}$, which makes the integral a constant (wrt y) times $\int e^y dy = \infty$.

Comment: $f'$ is also bounded. Sorry.

Comment: Can you please also answer Umberto's question: Is $I$ supposed to depend on the value of $x$?

Comment: so you are not answering Umbertos question and just leaving the arena instead?

Comment: I don't think that bounding $f'$ is enough to save this. Let $f'(y) = 4 + \arctan y$. So $|f'| = f'$ and since $f'$ is increasing, $\sup_{z \in B(x-y,1)} |f'(z)| = f'(x + 1 - y)$. So the integral is just $\int 4+\arctan(x+1-y)dy$ which is still unbounded ($\int \arctan(\theta) d\theta = \theta \arctan \theta - (1/2) \log(1+\theta^2) + C$)

Comment: thanks Paul :-) by the way: actually the integral does not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: my first answer is wrong. This was my first answer:**

if $f'$ is also bounded (by $K\geq 0$) then $\int_{z\in B\left(x-y,1\right)}\left|f'\left(z\right)\right|\mathrm{d}y\leq \int_{z\in B\left(x-y,1\right)}K\mathrm{d}y= K\cdot \int_{z\in B\left(x-y,1\right)}1\mathrm{d}y \leq 2\cdot K$

**EDIT: This is my suggested correction:**

$y\mapsto\sup_{z:\left|x-z\right|\leq 1} \left|f'\left(z\right)\right|$ must be dominated by an integrable function and $\left|f'\right|$ must be bounded.

One way to archieve that is for instance by assuming that $\left|f'\right|$ is decreasing faster than $\mathbb{R}_{+}\ni x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$, i.e. it must hold, that $\exists M\geq 0,  C\geq 0, \alpha > 1$ such that $\left|f'\left(x\right)\right|\leq C\cdot\left|x\right|^{-\alpha}$ for $\left|x\right|\geq M$.

note: also other criteria are sufficient to have that integrability. the condition I suggested is not the only one possible here. The proof is the same.

if now $f'$ is also bounded by $K\geq 0$, then $\int \sup_{z\in B\left(x-y,1\right)}\left|f'\left(z\right)\right|\mathrm{d}y\leq \int_{\left|y\right|\leq M+1}\sup_{z\in B\left(x-y,1\right)}K\mathrm{d}y+\int_{y>M+1}C\cdot\left|y-1\right|^{-\alpha}\leq 2\cdot\left(M+1\right)\cdot K + \int_{\left|y \right|\geq M}\left|y\right|^{-\alpha}\mathrm{d}y$ which is finite for $\alpha$ strictly greater than $1$.

if $f'$ is not bounded, then there is an Interval $J$ such that $\sup_{J}\left|f'\right|$ equals infinity.

Comment: It is the supremum that is limited to $B(x - y,1)$ not the integration.

Comment: do you have $\exists K\geq 0:\forall r\in\mathbb{R}:\left|f'\left(r\right)\right|\leq K$ or not? If the Bound is only uniform for fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then for every $K\geq0$ there is an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $I\left(x\right)\geq K$

Comment: If you need a proof for this just ask, but i think it is obvious.